# boost-log stat_collector example does not work

Tags: boost

I'm using boost 1.54, VS2012 on Windows 7.
I can step into logging::add_value("Sent", 100u) and see the constructor for add_value_manip work correctly with m_value = 100 and m_id = 8.  By the time basic_record_ostream.operator<< is called the manip parameter has the m_value at 2130567168.  Incorrect values are of course found in the stat_collector.consume method as well as being written out to csv file.

This example code is found in the html doc for boost log Minimalistic sink backend with code under libs\log\example\doc\extension_stat_collector.cpp

Comment: I did file one before 1.55 and was hoping to see it fixed in 1.55.

Comment: Here is link on bug report: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9320 . Looks like it's included from version 1.56.